# add a show password button inside of input field - crispy forms

Tags: html, jquery, css, django, django-crispy-forms

I want to add a show password button inside of the password input field.
I am using crispy forms for styling so I am a little bit stuck on the best practice here.

Currently I have a seperate checkbox field which is showing the password on check. Js is working fine here.
I'd like to change de checkbox to a eye icon which is inside of the input field.
I've managed to add the eye icon to the input field via css background: url(path-to-icon).

I can't figure out how to change the icon to a button (1) and add my js to it (2).

My form:

```
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    user_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.exclude(name='admin').exclude(name='personeel').exclude(name='onderhoud'),
                                        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'placeholder': 'Soort klant:'}),
                                        initial=('particulier'), label='Soort klant'
                                        )
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                                 label='Voornaam',
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Voornaam'}),)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, 
                                label='Achternaam',
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Achternaam'}),)
```

My HTML :

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        <a>{{ form.password1 | as_crispy_field}}</a>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        <a>{{ form.password2 | as_crispy_field}}</a>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
        <input class="ml-2" type="checkbox" onclick="ShowPassword()"> show password
   </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
#id_password1 {
    background: url("http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/user/media/eye_icon.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: right;
    background-position-x: 97%;
}

#id_password2 {
    background: url("http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/user/media/eye_icon.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: right 10px;
    background-position-x: 97%;
}
```

My js :

```
function ShowPassword() {
    var x = document.getElementById("id_password");
      if (x.type === "password") {
       x.type = "text";
       } else {
       x.type = "password";
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it almost!

Did everything in HTML, CSS and JS.

HTML

```
<a>{{ form.password2 | as_crispy_field}}</a>
<button class="toggle-password ml-2 fa fa-eye"></button>
```

CSS

```
.toggle-password {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 6%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML

```
$("body").on('click','.toggle-password',function(){
    var $pass1 = document.getElementById("id_password1");
    var $pass2 = document.getElementById("id_password2");
    var toggle = $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
    [$pass1, $pass2].forEach(function($passwords) {
        if ($passwords.type === "password") {
        $passwords.type = "text";
        toggle.toggleClass()
        } else {
        $passwords.type = "password";
        }
    })

});
```

Still figuring out how to make both icons toggle at the same time. Now they doing it seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try font awesome ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Add this to base.html

```
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
```

Add this where ever you'd like to place the icon.

```
.btn{
  cursor: pointer;
   }
 .btn-hover{
   background-color:YourChoice;
   }
```

Add this to your css file accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Made this work properly only need to make a custom input field with the button inside of the field via the crispy form helper. Can't figure out how to do this though. Got something like this right now:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('password1', on_click="ShowPassword()")
        )
```

My working button right now:

```
<input type="image" class="ml-2" src="/static/user/media/eye_icon.png" onclick="ShowPassword()" id="show-password-button">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
Field(
 PrependedText('password',mark_safe('<span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>'), placeholder=_("Enter Password")))
```